# VB.NET 2010 & MS Access 2010 - Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.Net 2010. Here is my problem: I have a query that uses a combo box to fetch many items in tblKBA. All IDs in the MS Access database are integers. The combo box display member and value member is set to the asset and ID of tblProducts.

myQuery = "SELECT id, desc, solution FROM tblKBA WHERE tblKBA.product_id =  '"  + cmbProducts.SelectedValue + "'"

In addition to getting items from the KBA table, I want to fetch the department details from the department table, possibly done in the same query. I am trying to do it in two separate queries.

myQuery = "select telephone, desc, website from tblDepartments where tblDepartments.product_id = tblProducts.id and tblProducts.id = '" + cmbProducts.SelectedValue + "' "

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change the '+' to a '&' then the compiler would be happy.

Comment: VB can use either + or &.  The + can either do math OR concantenate.  The & will only concantenate.  In some cases depending on what you are concantenating, it is necessary to use & to avoid the + doing math.

Comment: That's why I wrote to use the &.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `.toString` to `cmbproducts.selectedvalue` or do `"tblKBA.product_id.equals(" & cmbProducts.selectedValue.toString & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

1.) Don't use string concatenation to build your query.  Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx#Y423).

2.) I am guessing that tblKBA.product_id is a double and not a string, so don't put quotes around it.

```
myQuery = "SELECT id, desc FROM tblKBA WHERE tblKBA.product_id = ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

3 things.  Test your value before building the select statement.  Second, Use .SelectedItem.Value instead of .SelectedValue.  Third, protect yourself from sql injection attack.  Use parameters, or at the very least check for ' values.

```
  If IsNumeric(cmbProducts.SelectedItem.Value) = False Then
    'No valid value
    Return
  End If
  myQuery = String.Format("SELECT id, desc FROM tblKBA WHERE tblKBA.product_id = {0}", cmbProducts.SelectedItem.Value.Replace("'", "''"))
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the last line? You have a numerics with single quotes?

Comment: No, its doubling any 's to prevent sql injection attack.  Its not foolproof, but its better than nothing.  Technically cmbProducts.SelectedItem.Value is a string, and even though I am doing a test for numeric above, its still a good practice if you build sql statements without parameters.  Parameters is a much better practice though.